# SQL select only those group for which other column has only Nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL query with GROUP BY.
I want to select only this groups which have only Nulls in other column.

```
Select HH, TT from TABLE join TABLE... where XX GROUP BY HH

HH | TT 
1  | Null
2  | Null
2  | Test
3  | Null
3  | Null
```

I want to have only those:

```
 HH | TT 
 1  | Null
 3  | Null
```

I'm on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `group by` and `having`. Count of column TT should return 0 (as `count` ignores nulls).

```
select HH,max(TT) as TT
from tbl
group by HH
having count(TT)=0
```

Comment: It's working and give me same results like one above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`nvl2` is such a nice function that helps us for both `null` and `not null` values :

```
select hh, 'Null' tt
  from mytable
 group by hh
 having sum(nvl2(tt,1,0))=0;
```

Comment: It's working and give me same results like one below. Thanks.